# Unable to receive debug messages for crashing cordova app on windows 8.1 phone device

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I have VS 2015 Enterprise RC installed and am in the process of porting a Cordova app, deployed on iOS and Android, to Windows 8.1 Phone / Universal

After making the necessary changes I have an **App that crashes shortly after the splash screen is displayed on device**.

I don't see any error messages in visual studio Error / Output windows or on the device. The app just vanishes

Can anyone provide a method to capture information surrounding critical app failure on the device in VS or otherwise for debug purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was because you got a native exception which cannot be captured by current debugger type. In classic windows phone project like c# and winjs project, we can set the debugger type to support both managed and native. I think it's worth to try if you can get more info by enable native debugger.

By default, for Cordova project, the default debugger type is Script only. We can find it out by enable Diagnostic build log: Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions -> change "MSBuild project build output verbosity" to Diagnostic.

Then let's take an example to show what we can find:

1. Create a new black cordova project.
2. Change Solution Platform to Windows Phone (Universal) and select "Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB".
3. Build the solution. Then let's check the build log in output window.

When searching "debuggertype" in output window, we will be able to find the following info:

```
DebuggerFlavor = PhoneEmulator81Wvga4512
DebuggerType = Script
DebugSymbols = false
DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroupDependsOn =
DefaultContentType = Default
DefaultReferenceGroup = Implicit (Apache Cordova)
DefineCommonReferenceSchemas =
DefineExplicitDefaults = true
```

We can see the DebuggerType was set to Script. This is inherited from globle settings in MSBuild. You will be able to find what the file is from the Diagnostic build output log as well.

Then let's see how we can change it to capture native exceptions. Go to your project folder and open .jsproj.user file. We can find the following setting:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Windows Phone (Universal)'">
    <DebuggerFlavor>PhoneEmulator81Wvga4512</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Now, change it to the following will change the debugger type, you can verify that in build log.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Windows Phone (Universal)'">
    <DebuggerType>Mixed</DebuggerType>
    <DebuggerFlavor>PhoneEmulator81Wvga4512</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then you can run your app again to see if it will get any info in your visual studio output windows.

Comment: Nice instructions, but then i am not able to debug my application, because of this error: `The debugger does not support debugging managed and native code at the same time on this platform`

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, debugging the solution from the `platform/windows` directory is easier but I don't know if that will help in your situation.

There is also [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console) that helps with `console.log` logging.

The most popular bug in Windows Phone 8.1 / Universal Cordova apps is using libraries that manipulates DOM without [Winstore Jscompat library](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/winstore-jscompat). If you are using Angular, Ember, Knockout or something similar it causes the crash with first operation on DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone collects all crash data in a dump file. Activate this feature under:

> Settings > Reports

After that, the dump files are created in the following folder on the phone:

> WindowsPhone/Phone/Documents/Debug/

You can open an analyze them with Visual Studio.